# PHP Codeigniter encrypt password and email Sending

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am using below code to generate encrypted password and send mail through the user however I have a if condition below which used to update user details with the new password and send mail to the user, After If condition code is not getting into the loop and not sending any mail can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance

```
$this->load->model('employee/employee','employee'); //If saving is success, then send the email with the new password
$recovery_password = $this->auth_bundle->randomKey(); //Auto generate the unique password
$encrypted_recovery_password    = $this->auth_bundle->encryptPassword($recovery_password); //Encrypt the password and save in db

if($this->employee->update(array('password'=>$encrypted_recovery_password),array('email'=>$email))) {
    $this->load->model('auth/users','users');
    $userDetails = $this->users->getUserByEmail($email);

    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->from($this->config->item('website_email'), $this->config->item('website_email_name'));
    $this->email->to($email);
    $this->email->subject('Account Recovery Details');
    $message     =  "Hi ".$userDetails['firstname']." ".$userDetails['lastname'].",<br />";
    $message    .=  "Click here ".base_url()." and login with the following credentials.<br/><br/>";
    $message    .=  "Email - ".$email."<br/>";
    $message    .=  "Password - ".$recovery_password."<br/><br/>";
    $message    .=  "In case any queries or problems with Logging-In, please contact your manager<br /><br />";
    $message    .=  "Thank you,<br/>";
    $message    .=  $this->config->item('company_name');
    $this->email->message($message);

    if($this->email->send()) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('status','Recovery password has been successfully sent to your Email');
        redirect('auth/success');
    }else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Error in recovering your password. Please try again');
        redirect('auth/forgotPassword');
    }
}else {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Error in recovering your password. Please try again');
    redirect('auth/forgotPassword');
}
```

Comment: show your `$this->employee->update()` method

Comment: Its in the model that I have created

Comment: user information properly updated. right?

Comment: i guess your password is not storing in the database , please confirm it before sending the email that new random password was  updated in the database correctly.

Comment: Yes password is storing into database

Comment: @Razib AI Mamun:  Yes

Comment: After I enter email ID and click on recover button it is showing me below  message on the browser and updating the DB but not able to send mail to the user UPDATE `employees` SET `password` = 'e090d0d33f31f3eaa50b8fb8ce1faa431f5bec1409e09164a36b323facd8ad817647aad8ad436e40ce97051258750d33bbdfb771bf547066353d459082dc658b' WHERE `email` = 'xyz@gmail.com'

Comment: Guys I have sorted this issue Thanks for your help:)